# cocoa: index for CALayer

Tags: cocoa, calayer, nsview

I am doing some advanced drawing in my NSView subclass using CALayers using  `-(void) drawLayer:(CALayer *)layer inContext:(CGContextRef)ctx` In this callback I am given a CALayer, but I need to know the z-index of that layer in an arbitrarily large list of layers (all of which are sublayers of the root layer).

I tried `int index = [self.layer.sublayers indexOfObject:someCALayer];` but this does not seem to work.

How can I determine the index of a CALayer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up setting the z-index property of each CALayer as I added them, and used that to determine position.

```
for (int x = 0; x < NUM_LAYERS; x++) {
   CALayer* layer = [[CALayer alloc] init];
   // initialize stuff
   layer.zPosition = x;
   [self.layer addSublayer:layer];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no method `-drawFrameLayer:inContext:` in CoreAnimation or AppKit, so it's hard to say much definite about the layer it's providing. (I assume it comes from some 3rd-party framework?)

A guess:

Generally, the layers you work with are part of CoreAnimation's "model tree". Internally, CA makes copies of those layers, which are the "presentation tree". You can find the corresponding copy using the `-modelLayer` and `-presentationLayer` methods.

So, if the layer you're given is in the presentation tree, this might work:

```
[self.layer.sublayers indexOfObject:someCALayer.modelLayer]
```

Comment: Forgive me, that was a typo in the question (but not in my code). Fixed to `-(void) drawLayer:(CALayer *)layer inContext:(CGContextRef)ctx`